# what's wrong with the golang code by using ticker

Tags: go, channel, ticker

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    intChan := make(chan int, 1)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    go func() {
        for _ = range ticker.C {
            select {
            case intChan <- 1:
            case intChan <- 2:
            case intChan <- 3:
            }
        }
        /*defer */
        fmt.Println("End. [sender]")
    }()
    var sum int
    for e := range intChan {
        fmt.Printf("Received: %v\n", e)
        sum += e
        if sum > 10 {
            fmt.Printf("Got: %v\n", sum)
            break
            //ticker.Stop()
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("End. [receiver]")
    //time.Sleep(10)
}
```

I'm new in golang. In this code, I want print "End. [sender]" once when the goroutine is over. 
I try to use ticker.stop()， or even time.sleep(), defer , but no effect.
What's wrong with it, please give me some idea. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker.Stop) says, ticker.Stop doesn't close channel. So you must not expect break-loop. You can add new channel for quit.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    intChan := make(chan int, 2)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    quit := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
    loop:
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                select {
                case intChan <- 1:
                case intChan <- 2:
                case intChan <- 3:
                }
            case <-quit:
                break loop
            }
        }
        /*defer */
        fmt.Println("End. [sender]")
        close(intChan)
    }()
    var sum int
    for e := range intChan {
        fmt.Printf("Received: %v\n", e)
        sum += e
        if sum > 10 {
            fmt.Printf("Got: %v\n", sum)
            quit <- true
            //break
            //ticker.Stop()
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("End. [receiver]")
    //time.Sleep(10)
}
```